# Contract work in Germany for UK Resident

Tags: schengen-visas, uk-residents

If a non-EU is a resident (not permanent but eligible to work in UK) in the UK and he or she wants to frequently travel to Germany for business for a few months, what's the best way to do this?

Will a letter from the business in Germany suffice? What are the visa options if this were for a project lasting 3 to 6 months? Obviously the goal is to obtain some sort of multi entry visa.

Thanks.

Comment: After 91 days, it gets tricky. Possibly then, definitely at 183 days, you will become German resident & liable for texts there. Also, this might be better asked at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mawg, I believe you made a small but significant typo. Taxes.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant all right :-)

Comment: It's a 3 month contract that may be renewed. What visa works if it's less than 90 days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to do in Germany, you might need a residence and work permit. Otherwise, you would apply for a C Schengen visa for the *first* visit and mention that more will follow.

Summarized, a C visa allows you to come to Germany and **talk about work**, you need a work permit to come to Germany and **do work**.

Usually first-time Schengen visa are single-entry visa with a duration for just one trip. After several applications without incidents like overstay, they give longer multi-entry visa. For an UK resident with a stable job, it would be *relatively* likely to get a multi-entry visa soon.

For residence permits, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.